# How to shutdown and start cloudera cluster safely

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am using CDH 5.3 on muiltinode cluster and on top of this I have installed Hive, Hbase, Pig and zookeeper. It has total 5 nodes.
Recently server was shutdown to upgrade number of cores in each node. First all datanodes' services were stopped and later name node services.

Below commands were used to stop all services:

**DataNode:**

1. sudo service hbase-regionserver stop
2. sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop
3. sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode stop

**Name Node:**

1. sudo service  mysql stop
2. sudo service  hive-metastore stop
3. sudo service  zookeeper-server stop
4. sudo service  hbase-master stop
5. sudo service  hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
6. sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop
7. sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode stop

While starting this cluster, name node was started first and then all datanodes.
But when it was started, name node was not coming out of safe mode, even when all datanodes were up. Almost all the files in HDFS were corrupted. Hive metastore and hbase name space was corrupted. Due to this all data got removed from cluster.

Could anyone please give me steps on how to stop all the services and start the cluster back.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you use Cloudera Manager UI? It has stop and start cluster actions, so there should be no issues with that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hbase name space was corrupted'? Was it /hbase/.logs directory that was corrupted or the entire /hbase directory, after removing broken WAL logs?

Comment: I have not istalled cloudera manager. I am using only CDH5.3.  
 hbase namespace is the internal namespace HBAse uses for its own management tables. I  ran the offline repair tool from the $HBASE_HOME directory:

 ./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair 
 I deleted /hbase folder in HDFS as well and created it back.

Comment: I have the same probem, any idea?